# How do you sort a range of lines by length?

Tags: regex, sorting, vim

Often I just want to sort all my `#include`'s at the top of my source and header files by their length.

`vim` allows me to sort alphanumerically in a similar manner with `:{range} sort u`.

In `vim`, how do you sort a range of lines by the length of the line?  Such that shorter lines are followed by longer lines.

Searching the internet, I found this:

```
:% s/.*/\=printf("%03d", len(submatch(0)))."|".submatch(0)/ | sor n | %s/..../
```

But that only works to sort the entire file, and is black magic to me anyway.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that same sort with a range such as from line 4 to 18, as in `:4,18 s/...` Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Filter Visual Selection with Awk

One way to do this in vim is by filtering the visual selection with awk's length() function before sorting. For example:

```
:'<,'> ! awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -n | cut -d\\  -f2-" }'
```

Comment: @CoryKlein That *is* a range. The example just specifies it using vim's visual selection (lines selected with `SHIFT-V + <MOTION>`). If you want line addresses, just replace `'<,'>` with any other valid address specification (e.g. `5,12`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I didn't really understand the syntax of `'<,'>`, and it's good to know that this is just another way to specify a range, and that this is how you specify the range of the visual selection.

Comment: Even with awk installed on my Windows system this still fails for me

Answer (score 8):

One way, neither elegant nor efficient, but it works:

Add following function to your `vimrc` file. It inserts at the beginning of each line its number of characters, sort them numerically and deletes the numbers.

```
function! SortLines() range
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\(.*\)$/\=strdisplaywidth( submatch(0) ) . " " . submatch(0)/'
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 'sort n'
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 's/^\d\+\s//'
endfunction
```

Call it with a range of numbers, like

```
:4,18call SortLines()
```

or in Visual mode using `V`, like:

```
:'<,'>call SortLines()
```

**EDIT**: Ops, now I realised that this solution is very similar to yours. It was fine, only that `%` means the complete buffer instead `:4,18` or `:'<,:'>` that selects specific lines.

Comment: Attention! `strlen()` counts the number of bytes used to represent the character, so you may get unexpected results for non-ASCII characters. Better use `strchars()` for the number of characters, or `strdisplaywidth()` if you want to sort by the displayed length (which can differ when <Tab> and double-width characters are involved).

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Thank you very much, +1. I modified the answer to use `strdisplaywidth()`. I liked it more but the OP should read your comment to choose his best.

Comment: @Birei I'm giving the answer to you because although the solution uses more lines of code, you have put it into a function, making it easier for me to use in the future, whereas I won't be able to remember (nor want to type) CodeGnome's solution, and I'm not familiar enough with `vim` functions to make his answer into a function.

Comment: This answer purely relies on Vim and so works cross platform

Comment: @Birei Will it also work if I put the function in to ~\.gvimrc file?

Answer (score 8):

I've written the [AdvancedSorters plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) to deal with these complex sorting requirements.

Like in @Birei's answer, this plugin offers extension commands that evaluate an expression per line,
put that number in front of the line, do a numerical sort, and then remove the
temporary number again. Specializations handle the common sort by number of
characters and by the line's display width, so you could just use:

```
:SortByWidth
```

Comment: That's nice! Could you please update your repository on github: https://github.com/vim-scripts/AdvancedSorters so I can install it with vim-plug?

Comment: @TornaxO7: That is not my repository, it's a mirror of all vim.org plugins that has been discontinued. Through the [vim.org plugin page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) you can reach my own [GitHub repository](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-AdvancedSorters); this contains the latest published 1.30 version.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Does this plugin works with gVim 8+. I copied the AdvancedSorters.vim file to my $HOME/vimfiles/plugin/ and it gave me a lot of errors when I restarted gVim.

Comment: @anishjp You also need to install my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433); also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library). It's listed as a DEPENDENCY in the plugin's INSTALLATION section.