# VIM: Sort python multiline imports

Tags: python, sorting, vim

Is there any way to sort multiline imports with vim built-in functionality (alphabetically)?

E.g.

```
import Fred
import Foo, Baz,\
     Bar, Spam, Eggs
import Python
```

Should become:

```
import Foo, Baz,\
     Bar, Spam, Eggs
import Fred
import Python
```

I've checked :help sort. Especially the pattern matching comes close to what I want, but it leaves the imported classes separate under the sorted block.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531073/how-do-you-sort-a-range-of-lines-by-length

Comment: I think when you start to want to order your imports alphabetically, you may be a little too far on the "polishing code" road. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim can only sort by line. So you can

- replace `\\\n` to `|`
- sort
- replace `|` to `\\\n`

---

Try this:

```
:%s/\\\@<=\n/|
:sort
:%s/\\\@<=|/\r
```

**Note:** `\@<=` is the same as `\zs` here.

Comment: I understand. So all you do is, "marking" all newline separators with a "|", which also joins all lines. Now I can sort. The third line, simply replaces all "markers" with the previous newline separators? Seems to be good enough for me :) Cheers!!!

Comment: ugly as it is, this is what I used today. Perhaps... a plugin should be made :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not fully relevant but this question is among first Google hits for `vim sort python imports`, so I'll leave it here:

If you don't worry about multiline imports but want to handle both `import xyz` and `from xyz import xyz` forms then the following command will help you:

```
:sort /[if][^ ]*/
```

This means "ignore anything matching the pattern and sort by what comes next".