# How to sort a range of lines by length in vim with gawk?

Tags: vim, awk, gawk, viml

Short question i'm using this regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531819/4779063 to sort lines by lenght in vim but i modified it a little bit to make it work with windows and [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) so i end up having something like this:

```
  vmap <Leader>su ! gawk -f "{ print length(), $0 \| \"sort -n \| cut -d\\  -f2-\"}"<CR>
```

but everytime i try to use it it says that it could open a .tmp file in my C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\VIi33.tmp

any ideas?

Comment: don't you need the `:` before `!`?

Comment: @Kent Since i'm mapping to visual mode, it automatically adds `:'<,'>` at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can try to **do that by using only vim** to sort your file by length:

```
:g/^/ s/^.*$/\=substitute(submatch(0),submatch(0),strlen(submatch(0)).'# '.submatch(0),'')/ 
:% sort! n
:% s/^\d\+# //
```

Comment: It kind of gets the jobs done (some lines for whatever reason are missplaced) but thing is; those commands are for the all file, and i'm looking to order just what i select on visual mode

Comment: If you want to do that you have only to select every time the block and execute every command. I don't figure out a better way to do that and I found it difficult to execute the three commands in pipelined one  .

Answer (score 1):

This GNU AWK program sorts records or lines (via an array) based on their length and prints them out in sorted order.  Could you use that?

```
function len_comp_func(i1,v1,i2,v2) {   # define length comparison function for for
  return(length(v1)-length(v2))
}
{
  arr[NR]=$0                            # populate array with all the records
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "comp_func"   # define order function
  for (i in arr)                        # traverse in length order
    print arr[i]
}
```

.